# Debug Assertion Failed: C++ exception in a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, printf, release

I have been managing and updating a particular application. It is old and I am not the original developer. It's suffered through several debugging sessions over the years among other small patches.

It has been running stable for the last couple of months, but then an exception occurred that seems odd to me. Since this only happens on the server ( it is a server application. ) in release mode.

The application is written in C#, is managed in Visual Studio 2012 Professional and is released to be explicitly 32-bit .NET 3.5 since the server is unfortunately running Windows 2003. (I have tried to convince them to update so I can update the application to .NET 4.5. But alas.)

So I am getting a C++ Debug message. See the screenshot below. It occurs in a file named vsprintf.c I am guessing on line 91. The only message that gives me any hint is format != NULL.

This confuses me however. What can possibly cause this? What steps can I best take to debug in a situation like this? What is "vsprintf.c"?

[image: Exception]

Edit: I managed to find something in eventviewer. I will continue to research this in the meanwhile.

[image: Eventviewer]

Sincerely,

me.

Comment: `vsprintf` is a standard function. You need to inspect the call stack.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I have not been able to reproduce this on the development machine. Also the server administrator restarted the application before I could have a look myself.

Comment: @Simple how can he do that with assert? On the other hand, meanwhile DavideNgueyen seems to have had some progress reproducing the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an assertion failure, ie an assumtion that a function you are calling makes is not met, in this case that a pointer is not null. From the looks of it, its a format string. Are you using format strings directly? If so, look there. If not, this is probably a memory leak problem, followed by an out-of-memory malfunction.

Comment: I ruled out it being a memory leak by looking at the memory use graphic in the VM Manager

Comment: [+1] for the great guess! @DavideNguyen: then you would be able to reproduce this on you development machine - if you produce enough load?

Comment: This is unlikely as the server machine has physical over 16GB of RAM, the virtual machine has 4GB of ram. (Which is more then enough.) While as my developement system has an effective 3GB of ram because it runs windows 7 32-bit. WE use old ODBC drivers for other applications to communicate with our stone age UNIMS datasources. What is strange is that the error is a one time error and it hasn't occurred again so far. I don't have a test case and nothing out of the ordinary happens on our parallel test environment.

Comment: Also the application is measured to run within the .NET default max-memory. I used to have an issue with that before, extended it through a fix and solved the memory bulking before. The application uses less than 900 MB of memory when at it's peak.  (It does alot within the company.)

Comment: It was a memory bloating, yep.

Answer (score 0):

`vsprintf` calls can be caused by `sprintf` and other derivates, you should maybe check all these calls. (This can also be methods of string classes, as I saw in the VCL).

If the bug isn't caused by one of the libraries you use, then there should be a `NULL` (or `0`) in the *format string parameter*, which is mostly the last before the `...` in the prototype.

If you are familiar with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples), this may help a lot when looking for patterns.

Comment: I am reviewing the code but I doubt I will find anything that will strike me as odd.

Comment: @DavideNguyen Did you find any direct calls to functions with `sprintf` in its names?

Comment: No, a complete search did not show any calls to sprintf or vsprintf.

Comment: @DavideNguyen I see. Does your application use formatted output at all?

Comment: With that you mean string.Format fuctions aswell as StringBuilder? In that case, yes. It convers database orders into an EDI text format file that we import into our ERP.

Comment: @DavideNguyen Yes, I thought of that, but here we have a defined behaviour with `format` parameters being `null` (used for [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`StringBuilder.AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hdekwk0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)): the [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)